# Comfortable-mexican-sofa rich text editor not working with Rails4

Tags: content-management-system, rich-text-editor, ruby-on-rails-4.1, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I want to use default rich text editor for comfy-mexican-sofa, as per the guidelines I used :data => {'cms-rich-text'=> 'true'}, but it is not working also not showing any error.

```
ruby version-2.2.0
rails version- 4.1.5
```

Tell me if I am missing anything.
form.html.haml:

```
= form.text_area :content, :data => {'cms-rich-text'=> 'true'}
= form.check_box :is_banner
= form.file_field :logo_image
= form.form_group :class => 'form-actions' do
= form.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary'

application.js:
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
// require turbolinks
//= require custom
//= require stripe
//= require databases
//= require rich
//= require highcharts
//= require_tree .
```

Immediate reply will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `:data => {'cms-rich`enter code here`-text'=> 'true'}` ???

Comment: Hi Grocery,
There was some typo. its like this  :data => {'cms-rich-text'=> 'true'}

Comment: Are you trying to use that wysiwyg inside CMS admin area? Make sure that CMS javascript is actually being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout editor window, change the following (the tag is irrelevant, the change is the main point):

THIS:
{{ cms:page:right_column }}

TO:
{{ cms:page:right_column:rich_text }}

...and the editor will appear for the window you define this change on.

Comment: If this answer is the solution, would you mind doing me a favor and marking this entry as the answer? I am one of those strange people who cares way too much about his StackOverflow scores... :)